# Can I make RandomInstance use exact arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, synthetic-geometry

When using `RandomInstance` on a `GeometricScene` the answer loses precision when root objects are encountered. Is there a way to make `RandomInstance` work with exact numbers?

For example consider the following:

```
scene = 
  GeometricScene[{"O","TA","IA","F"},
    {
    "O" == {0, 0},
    "IA" == {4Sqrt[2], 0},
    EuclideanDistance["O", "TA"] == 4 Sqrt[2],
    PlanarAngle[{"IA", "O", "TA"}, "Counterclockwise"] == 240 °
    }];
```

Grabbing the point `"TA"` produces an inexact result:

```
"TA" /. RandomInstance[scene]["Points"]
```

How can I make it get the exact answer?

Comment: Sadly, no. It is a big weakness in the new synthetic geometry system. I reported it to Wolfram tech support awhile ago. In some cases, a reformulation of the problem can fix it so machine precision works.

Comment: Actually, it isn't just "TA". All the points you specify are converted to machine precision.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking for functionality that does not exist in the current version of Mathematica.

Comment: In your example, the calculations are accurate enough that Mathematica recognizes that IA and TA have the same length. Is that what you wanted from it?

Comment: `"TA"/.RandomInstance[scene]["Points"]//RootApproximant` gives `{-2 Sqrt[2],-2 Sqrt[6]}`.

Comment: @chyanog Thank you `RootApproximant` will do for now! But if somebody knows an internal switch that might make the `RandomInstance` work for exact numbers that would be lovely. I could see they may have done it to make the calculations run faster for the synthetic geometry system.

Comment: @m_goldberg  This question does not need to be closed, nor should it.  The OP's question squarely falls within the scope of this site.  The question is _Is it possible to make `RandomInstance` work with exact numbers?_ The answer is simply _no_.

Comment: @QuantumDot. Yes, it is a legitimate question for this site, but what the OP asks for is simply not possible, so why keep the question open?

Comment: @m_goldberg because there may be undocumented solutions.  In fact, a solution _could_ be found by exploring ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[RandomInstance]``.

Comment: @QuantumDot. Then you should post an answer giving that solution.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, all numeric quantities given in a `GeometricScene` expression are transformed to machine precision when `RandomInstance` is applied. This can be observed by evaluating the following code.

```
scene =
  GeometricScene[{"O", "TA", "IA"}, 
    {"O" == {0, 0},
     "IA" == {4 Sqrt[2], 0},
     EuclideanDistance["O", "TA"] == 4 Sqrt[2], 
     PlanarAngle[{"IA", "O", "TA"}, "Counterclockwise"] == 240 °}];
RandomInstance[scene] // InputForm
```

which produces

[image: scene]

Notice that, although the 2nd argument (the hypotheses) preserve the exact quantities you entered, in the 1st argument all the symbolic points have been associated with machine precision quantities and these are the quantities that will be used by `RandomInstance` and `FindGeometricConjectures` when making calculations. So there is no way `RandomInstance` will use exact arithmetic.

However, as explained by chyanog in a comment to your question, sometimes it is possible to recover the exact values from the results returned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can.  This seems to work, I guess, on the simple example:

```
RandomInstance[scene] /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x] // InputForm
(*
GeometricScene[{{"IA" -> {4*Sqrt[2], 0}, 
   "O" -> {0, 0}, "TA" -> {-2*Sqrt[2], 
     -2*Sqrt[6]}}, {}}, {"O" == {0, 0}, 
  "IA" == {4*Sqrt[2], 0}, 
  EuclideanDistance["O", "TA"] == 4*Sqrt[2], 
  PlanarAngle[{"IA", "O", "TA"}, 
    "Counterclockwise"] == 240*Degree}, {}]
*)
```